# Getting the actual webservice text as a string

Tags: .net, vb.net, web-services

I have situation here in which I have to store the actual webservice in database for audit purpose before performing any operations.

For instance: I have a web method which asks for 2 parameters

```
Sub MyWebMethod(i as int, j as int)
      StoreActualWebserviceInDatabase(CalledWebService.ToString)
      PerformOperation(i,j)
End Sub
```

I want the function StoreActualWebserviceInDatabase to store the invoked web service text in database. How to get this as a text/XML or something else?

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "the actual webservice"? Do you mean the response provided by the web service, in the form that it is propagated across the network? Assuming this is over HTTP, do you need all the HTTP response headers as well as the content?

Comment: If you were using WCF (as you should be) then you could easily use Message Logging to log the entire request and response to a database. You appear to have an ASMX service. Is that correct?

Comment: Hi,
I am calling this web service using similar code as given below:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Header>
<AuthHeader xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<Username>abcd</Username>
<Password>por</Password>
</AuthHeader>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
<MyWebMethod xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<i>5215</i>
<i>5.5</i>
</MyWebMethod>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

I need to store this in database.

Any suggestions?